# VBA : Paste Word.Table into Outlook email

Tags: outlook

I have the below VBA code which i run to create a reply email.

```
Dim Reply As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Original As Outlook.MailItem

Set Original = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)

Set Reply = Original.ReplyAll
Reply.Subject = "RE: " & Original.Subject
Reply.Display
```

I have the following variable and have been unsuccessfully trying to paste it into "Reply" above.

```
Dim tTable As Word.Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Word is used as an email editor in Outlook. You can use the [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class to get an instance of the Document class which represents the Body of the email. Thus, you will be able to use objects, their properties and methods available in the Word object model when working with item bodies.

You can read about all possible ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) article in MSDN.